# change Background By jquery for 1 product in page

Tags: jquery

I have one product page,
I want when mouse over the description of a product ,background be darker.But this is for all products, not one product

```js
$(".hover_fly .hover_fly_btn:first-child").mouseover(function() {
  $(" .overlay-desc").css({
    opacity: 0.1
  });
});

$(".hover_fly .hover_fly_btn:first-child").mouseout(function() {
  $(" .overlay-desc").css({
    opacity: 0
  });
});
```

```css
.overlay-desc {
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pro_outer_box">
  <div class="overlay-desc" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
  <a href="#">
    <img alt="Elit Royal Blue Border">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="hover_fly ">
  <a class="view_button hover_fly_btn  btn-spin" href="#" title="more info" rel="nofollow">
    <div class="hover_fly_btn_inner"> <span>more info</span></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you have to use something like ` $(this).closest(".hover_fly").prev('pro_outer_box.').find(" .overlay-desc")`

Answer (score 0):

if you can sign the HTML element with an univocal ID so you can use it as selector

```
<div class="pro_outer_box">
  <div id="overlayToOpen" class="overlay-desc" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
  <a href="#">
    <img alt="Elit Royal Blue Border">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="hover_fly ">
  <a id="showOverlay" class="view_button hover_fly_btn  btn-spin" href="#" title="more info" rel="nofollow">
    <div class="hover_fly_btn_inner"> <span>more info</span></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

and you JS becomes

```
$("#showOverlay").on('mouseenter', function(){
  $("#overlayToOpen").css({
    opacity: 0.1
  });
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
 $("#overlayToOpen").css({
    opacity: 0
  });
});
```

Comment: it should works, try to use an higher opacity for hover state, or to use .mouseenter()  and .mouseleave() instead of .on('mouseenter') and .on('mouseleave'). Also try to insert an alert in function so you can be sure that the code is trigged

Comment: thanks ...my mistake was in selction .I changed it to:
    $(".hover_fly .hover_fly_btn:first-child").mouseover(function(){

    $(this).parents('.pro_outer_box').find('.overlay-desc').css({ opacity: 0.1})
});